# Need help having a prototype method loop through an array

Tags: javascript

I am needing help with my javascript assignment.
I am getting the following error on part 2:

"`calcCartTotal()`
    ✓ should be defined as a prototype

1) calculates and returns the `totalCost` property

2) calculates and returns the `totalCost` property

1 passing (260ms)

2 failing

1) `calcCartTotal()`
       calculates and returns the `totalCost` property :
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
      at cart.calcCartTotal (rb_build.js:43:22)
      at Array.forEach ()
      at cart.calcCartTotal (rb_build.js:45:11)
      at Context. (nt-test-76b25d6e.js:40:18)

2) `calcCartTotal()`
       calculates and returns the `totalCost` property :
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
      at cart.calcCartTotal (rb_build.js:43:22)
      at Array.forEach ()
      at cart.calcCartTotal (rb_build.js:45:11)
      at Context. (nt-test-76b25d6e.js:57:18)`

Here is the assignment section I am on:

"Add the following methods to the cart and foodItem prototypes:

1. Add calcItemCost() to foodItem prototype. Have the method return the product of the price property multiplied by the qty property. (Hint: Use the this keyword to reference the foodItem object.)
2. Add calcCartTotal() to the cart prototype. Have the method, which calculates the cartTotal (the total cost of all items ordered), loop through the contents of the items array and apply the calcItemCost() method to each item in the array. Store the sum of the item costs in the totalCost property and return that value.
3. Add addToCart() to the foodItem prototype. The method has a single parameter named cart representing the shopping cart to which the item should be added. Use the push() Array method to add the foodItem object to the items array of the cart. (Hint: Use the this keyword to reference the foodItem object.)

   4. Add removeFromCart() to the foodItem prototype. The method has a single parameter named cart representing the shopping cart from which the item should be removed. Loop through the items array in the cart object and for each item test whether it is equal to the foodItem object. If it is, use the splice() method to remove the object from the items array and break off the for loop. (Hint: Use the this keyword to reference the foodItem object and use the splice(index, 1) to remove the foodItem where index is the counter variable in the for loop."

What I have so far:

```js
var pizzaPrice = {
  size12: 11,
  size14: 13,
  size16:  16,
  stuffed: 3,
  pan: 2,
  doubleSauce: 1.5, 
  doubleCheese: 1.5,
  topping: 1.5,
};

function cart () {
  this.totalCost = 0;
  this.items = [];
  }


function foodItem () {
  this.price
  this.qty 
}

foodItem.prototype.calcItemCost = function() {
  return this.price * this.qty;
};

  var calcItemCost = cart.prototype.calcCartTotal = function () {
 var cartTotal;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 items.forEach(calcItemCost);
    totalCost = totalCost + (items[i].qty * items[i].price);
  }
  return totalCost;
};

foodItem.prototype.addToCart = function () {
};

foodItem.prototype.removeFromCart = function () {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `items` from `cart`. You need to call them from `this` as you are trying to work with object property from it's prototype.

```
this.items.forEach()
```

More information [here](https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance)

Also you definately has some problems with code placement in your example...

Comment: I am a super beginner at javaScript :(. Once I add this.items.forEach(calcItemCost); It gives me an error that calcItemCost is not defined. How do I reference the calcItemCost method?

Comment: @ConstancePlas try to edit your code example - you misplaces code 100%. Staring from "var calcItemCost = cart.prototype.calcCartTotal" something going wrong